# SQL Server - adding nvarchar variable to email with html formatting

Tags: sql-server

I just can't see what I'm doing wrong but it's probably a simple issue.

I use `sp_send_dbmail` to send an email notification to users. The body of the email is formatted with html.

When I do tests, the body is blank. I've narrowed it down to the `@Name` variable. If I add a simple string like 'John' then the body is not blank, but I'm doing something wrong with the `@Name` variable.
I would think the `CAST` of `@Name` is unnecessary, but I've just been trying different things to no avail.

How do I incorporate `@Name` in a correct way?

Below is the code with parts of the irrelevant html left out to shorten it:

```
Alter Proc [dbo].[SendPayslipEmail] 
(@TVP EmailAddressTableType READONLY,
@Period NVARCHAR(50),
@Message NVARCHAR(MAX))

as

begin

DECLARE @ResTag INT
DECLARE @Email_Address VARCHAR(150)


DECLARE @emailHTML  NVARCHAR(MAX) ;
DECLARE @Subject NVARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @LoginURL NVARCHAR(50);
 

SET @Subject = (Select [Value] from [CustomerEmailSettings] where [Setting] = 'Payslip Email Subject')  
SET @LoginURL = (Select [Value] from [CustomerEmailSettings] where [Setting] = 'LoginURL')




DECLARE cursorSendEmail CURSOR
    FOR SELECT [Resource Tag],[E-mail Address] FROM @TVP;
    
OPEN cursorSendEmail  

FETCH NEXT FROM cursorSendEmail INTO @ResTag,@Email_Address;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

SET @Name = CAST((SELECT [Display Name] FROM DisplayName(@ResTag)) AS NVARCHAR(50)) 


SET @emailHTML = 

N'<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">'
+N'<head>'
<!-- More html -->
                    +N'<p class=MsoNormal><b><span style=''color:#4485B8''>Dear '

                    +@Name

                    +N',<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>'
    <!-- More html -->               
+N'</html>'

 EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
    @profile_name = 'PayslipEmails',  
    @recipients = @Email_Address,  
    @body =  @emailHTML, 
    @body_format = 'HTML', 
    @subject =  @Subject;
        

FETCH NEXT FROM cursorSendEmail INTO @ResTag,@Email_Address;
END

CLOSE cursorSendEmail
DEALLOCATE cursorSendEmail

end
```

Comment: If the body is blank this suggests that `@emailHTML` has the value `NULL`, which very likely means you're concatenating a `NULL` value to your string somewhere. `{varchar literal} + NULL + {varchar expression} = NULL`

Comment: Also, you have a `TOP 1` there without an `ORDER BY`; you should fix that.

Comment: @Larnu, true, I've removed the Top(1).

Comment: What is your @Name variable's value? Before sending please print and check it. I think Larnu is right and it's NULL.

Comment: @Larnu, thanks, you were right. My `@ResTag` in the stored procedure was different than the `@ResTag` I used to test elsewhere (which I didn't realise at first) and so `@Name` was indeed NULL.